# Using C code in Python returns strange values

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I wrote a function to get all prime numbers under n in C, and imported it into Python with ctypes.
The function however doesn't return what I expected.
How do I know the size of the returned `int*` pointer in Python:

primes.c file: It returns a `int*` pointer of all prime numbers under `n`

```
int* primes(int n)
{
  int i, j;
  int *primes = NULL;
  int *prime_numbers = NULL;
  int num_primes = 0;
  
  if (n < 3) {
    printf("n must be >= 3, you input n: %d\n", n);
    return NULL;
  }

  primes = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));

  if (primes == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    primes[i] = 1;
  }

  primes[0] = 0;
  primes[1] = 0;
  
  for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (primes[i]) {
      for (j = i*2; j < n; j += i) {
        primes[j] = 0;
      }
      num_primes++;
    }
  }

  j = 0;
  prime_numbers = (int *)calloc(num_primes, sizeof(int));

  if (prime_numbers == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (primes[i]) {
      prime_numbers[j] = i;
      j++;
    }
  }
  free(primes);
  return prime_numbers;
}
```

In Python:

```
import ctypes
from time import perf_counter

library = ctypes.CDLL('./primes.so')
library.primes.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
library.primes.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# --- Primes ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #


def primes_c(n: int) -> list[int]:
    assert isinstance(n, int), "n must be an integer."
    assert (n >= 3), "n must be >= 3."
    primes: list[int] = library.primes(n)
    return primes

def main():
    n: int = 10
    print(f"Getting prime numbers under {n:_}.")

    print("C implementation:")
    start = perf_counter()
    prime_numbers_c = primes_c(n)
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f"took {end - start:.2f} seconds.")

    for i in prime_numbers_c:
    print(i)

    libc.free(prime_numbers_c)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My output looks like this, segfaulting

```
.
.
.
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
[1]    28416 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python3 primes.py
```

Comment: You know the size of the pointer, but not the length of the data it points to. You have to specifically inform that too. One way to do that is to pass a double pointer to a buffer as an argument, which can be reallocated, and return the number of elements.

Comment: There's no way to know the size of the returned data in either C or Python.

Comment: Seems like you could use `itertools.islice(prime_numbers_c, n)` to get the n elements of that array.

Comment: @NickODell The returned array has less than n elements.

Comment: One way to solve this is to add a `0` at the end of the array, and make sure you don't read past it. By the way, annotating the function as returning `list[int]` when it's actually a ctypes pointer is highly misleading.

Comment: @interjay Thanks, this ended up working, I also changed the function annotation to "return" ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are a bunch of errors in the code:

- Showstopper: *SegFault* (*Access Violation*). You return a pointer from *C*, but in *Python* you go beyond its boundaries (when creating the list out of it), accessing memory that's not "yours" (***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*)
- *free*:

  - Calling it without "preparation". Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions)
  - A subtle one: You're crossing *.dll* boundary. Allocating a pointer in one side (the *.dll*) and freeing it in another (the *app*) yields *UB* if the 2 are built with different *C* runtimes (*C* runtime is statically linked in one of them). **When allocating memory in a *.dll*, also provide a function that deallocates it**
- Memory leak if the 2<sup>nd</sup> array allocation fails
- Some minor ones (including using the name *primes* for 2 separate things)

Now, In order to fix the (primary) error, you must tell the *primes* function caller how large the returned memory block is (for more details on this topic, check [[SO]: Pickling a ctypes.Structure with ct.Pointer (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72525657/4788546)). There is a number of ways to do that:

- Add a (*NULL*) sentinel at the end of the returned block (as @interjay pointed)
- Add an (output) argument to the function that will receive the number of primes
- Encapsulate the pointer and its size in a structure. Although it requires writing more code, that's the one I prefer

I prepared an example.

- *primes.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  typedef unsigned int uint;

  typedef struct Buffer_ {
      uint count;
      uint *data;
  } Buffer, *PBuffer;

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API PBuffer primesEratosthenes(uint n);
  DLL00_EXPORT_API void freePtr(PBuffer buf);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  PBuffer primesEratosthenes(uint n)
  {
      uint i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
      uint *sieve = NULL, *primes = NULL;
      PBuffer ret = NULL;

      if (n < 3) {
          printf("C - n must be >= 3, you input n: %u\n", n);
          return NULL;
      }

      sieve = malloc(n * sizeof(uint));
      if (sieve == NULL) {
          printf("C - Memory allocation failed 0\n");
          return NULL;
      }

      sieve[0] = 0;
      sieve[1] = 0;

      for (i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
          sieve[i] = 1;
      }

      for (i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
          if (sieve[i]) {
              for (j = i * 2; j < n; j += i) {
                  sieve[j] = 0;
              }
              ++count;
          }
      }

      primes = malloc(count * sizeof(uint));
      if (primes == NULL) {
          printf("C - Memory allocation failed 1\n");
          free(sieve);
          return NULL;
      }

      ret = malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
      if (ret == NULL) {
          printf("C - Memory allocation failed 2\n");
          free(primes);
          free(sieve);
          return NULL;
      }

      for (i = 2, j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          if (sieve[i]) {
              primes[j] = i;
              ++j;
          }
      }

      free(sieve);
      ret->count = count;
      ret->data = primes;
      return ret;
  }


  void freePtr(PBuffer buf)
  {
      if (buf == NULL) {
          return;
      }
      free(buf->data);
      free(buf);
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import sys
  from time import perf_counter


  DLL_NAME = "./primes.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")

  UIntPtr = cts.POINTER(cts.c_uint)


  class Buffer(cts.Structure):
      _fields_ = (
          ("count", cts.c_uint),
          ("data", UIntPtr),
      )

  BufferPtr = cts.POINTER(Buffer)


  def main(*argv):
      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
      primes_eratosthenes = dll.primesEratosthenes
      primes_eratosthenes.argtypes = (cts.c_int,)
      primes_eratosthenes.restype = BufferPtr
      free_ptr = dll.freePtr
      free_ptr.argtypes = (BufferPtr,)

      ns = (
          100,
          50000000,
      )

      funcs = (
          primes_eratosthenes,
      )

      for n in ns:
          print(f"Searching for primes until {n:d}")
          for func in funcs:
              start = perf_counter()
              pbuf = func(n)
              buf = pbuf.contents
              if not buf:
                  print("NULL ptr")
                  continue
              primes = buf.data[:buf.count]
              print(f"\n  Function {func.__name__} took {perf_counter() - start:.3f} seconds")
              print(f"  Found {buf.count:d} primes")
              if buf.count <= 100:
                  print(end="  ")
                  for i in primes:
                      print(i, end=" ")
                  print("\n")
              free_ptr(pbuf)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> (py_pc064_03.10_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076283276]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  primes.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o primes.so primes.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  primes.c  primes.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:10) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Searching for primes until 100
>
>   Function primesEratosthenes took 0.000 seconds
>   Found 25 primes
>   2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
>
> Searching for primes until 50000000
>
>   Function primesEratosthenes took 2.301 seconds
>   Found 3001134 primes
>
> Done.
> ```