# scipy installed, but import scipy fails, import numpy Ok

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cygwin, mingw

I need the error function, so am trying to install scipy. I believe I have numpy and scipy installed. I can use numpy just fine. For example:

```
>>>import numpy
>>>import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I get the same result if I do `>>>import scipy.special`. If I try to install scipy, it tells me it is already installed. If I force an install with
`$pip install --user --force-reinstall scipy` I get the following:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/51/046cbc61c7607e5ecead6ff1a9453fba5e7e47a5ea8d608cc7036586a5ef/scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from scipy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/40/c6eae19892551ff91bdb15f884fef2d42d6f58da55ab18fa540851b48a32/numpy-1.17.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.17.4
    Uninstalling numpy-1.17.4:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.17.4
  WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Found existing installation: scipy 1.4.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.1
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.4 scipy-1.4.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

It appears to install just fine. So why can't I use it? I am working in cygwin. I had not trouble at all installing and using scipy under windows. There must be something simple that I am doing wrong. I hope someone will tell me what it is. Please.

---

**Update 12/22/19**
A bit more detail. I have had cygwin on my computer for several years. I'm not sure when I got the cygwin version of Python and numpy. I installed mingw and python 7/5/19. Then I realized I needed the error function, so I tried to install scipy on both using pip. I was careful to install mingw in c:/mingw and cygwin in c:/cwin to make sure it was separate. pip doesn't seem to be very careful though. I posted a problem with f2py earlier -  [f2py linking quadmath libraries? Use ctypes for fortran wrapper instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923637/f2py-linking-quadmath-libraries-use-ctypes-for-fortran-wrapper-instead). It is probably related to this one.

Here is what I have now:

Installed by pip from cygwin prompt (see output above): 12/21/19:

```
    C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\site-packages\scipy & \numpy
```

Windows/mingw installed numpy 7/5/19, scipy installed by pip 8/2/19:

```
    C:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy & numpy
```

installed by Cygwin 6/27/2019

```
    C:\cwin\usr\python3.6\site-packages\numpy but no scipy
```

The versions installed by pip from the cygwin prompt (in roaming) aren't being accessed. Rather than change the path, I moved them over to the cygwin directory and tried to execute them from cygwin. I get the message:

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/_distributor_init.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ctypes import WinDLL
ImportError: cannot import name 'WinDLL'
```

These must be windows versions even though I installed them from the cygwin prompt. pip does not seem to work very well. I need an alternative installation method. Can someone advise????

Comment: Most likely something is missing from your PATH. Find the locations where both Scipy and Numpy are installed, and look at your environment variables. C:\Users\Larry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages is where I would expect to find it.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is all screwed up (see updated post). pip is not reliable. I would like to install scipy using the cygwin setup program, but I don't know which package would contain it. Can someone help?

Comment: As an experiment. I tried to install Pyton3.7 with the cygwin installer, which offers hundreds of boxes to check. I picked two boxes: Python37 and Python37-numpy. Predictably, numpy was installed, but not scipy. There is no category with scipy in the name. So where is it hidden? Which box needs to be checked?

Comment: If you want it to be crystal clear which python install pip is using, cd into the directory with python.exe, the use `python.exe -m pip install numpy` (or replace with scipy). Though at this point, it sounds like you might want to start with a clean/fresh install.